# How do you change the modal link color in Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have been trying for hours to figure out how to change the color of the text link that reveals a modal in Foundation. The default color for the text is black but I want it to be the same $primary-color as the other links in Foundation. Can anyone help me with this? I am new to CSS etc.

```
     <div>
      <ul class="inline-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-reveal-id="activitiesModal"><h3>Favorite Activities</h3></a></li>
        <li class="active right"><a href="#" data-reveal-id="eventsModal"><h3>Events I'm Attending</h3></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

      <div id="activitiesModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
        <h4 class="text-center">Stuff I Like</h4>
        <ul class="panel callout">
          <% @user.activities.each do |activity| %>
            <li class="text-center"><%= activity.name %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
      </div>
      <div id="eventsModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
        <h4 class="text-center"> Events I'm Attending </h4>
        <% @user.events.each do |event| %>
          <ul class="panel callout radius text-center">
            <li>Event: <%= event.activity.name %></li>
            <li>Start Time: <%= event.start_time.to_s(:format_time) %></li>
            <li>Location: <%= event.location_name %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'View Details', user_event_path(current_user, event) %></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `h3` is wrapped in an `a` that uses `$primary-color` you can use:

```
a[data-reveal-id] h3 {
    color: inherit;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iflCA

Comment: Why does this not work when I do it with the following (I am accounting for the <p>): <a href="#" data-reveal-id="attendeesModal" ><p>See Who's Attending</p></a>